# How do I redirect links in Wordpress posts to a subdirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, redirect, hyperlink

I am moving a WordPress site on my own server. It's set up on /var/www/public_html/wp/wordpress. So to go to my site, you'd go to example.com/wp/wordpress/. I added this line to public_html/.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /wp/wordpress/index.php [L]
```

So now example.com will go straight to WordPress. However, there are now a lot of broken links inside posts. These links usually point to example.com/webpage; the actual page can be found at example.com/wp/wordpress/index.php/webpage.

**How do I properly redirect these links?**

I can also run SQL commands on the WordPress database to fix the links directly (I'm using PHPMyAdmin).

*Edit:* Here are some screenshots. Apparently I'm not allowed to embed images yet, but here are some links.

[Here's a broken link, inside the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjQXO.png)

[Here's the resulting 404, when following that link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SEKw.png)

[And here's where the link is supposed to point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqO8A.png)

Just changing that one link wouldn't be a problem, but there are too many posts to go through to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your WordPress Admin Dashboard and go to permalinks and just click the save button even if you haven't change any setting on the permalinks settings.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything. The links to the posts themselves work fine, it's the links inside posts that are broken.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was going to comment before answering but I have no power to do just yet.

Comment: Can you please give any screenshots though.

Comment: So in general settings, did you set your new website link or change your old link to your new one?